# Prove $|a-b| \ge \left||a|-|b|\right|$ using the triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

So I feel I'm right at the end of this  proof... I just can't make the final step which is killing me.

I'm given $b=z_2$  and $a=z_1+z_2$ and must prove $|a-b|\ge \left||a|-|b|\right|$

And I've gotten this

$|a|-|b|\le|a-b|$

and

$|b|-|a|\le|a-b|$

I'm just stuck as to what I next do... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are done actually, since $||a|-|b||$ equals either $|b|-|a|$ or $|a|-|b|$.

Comment: If $|a|\ge|b|$, your first inequality says $|\,|a|-|b|\,|\le|a-b|$. If $|a|\lt|b|$, your second inequality says $|\,|a|-|b|\,|\le|a-b|$. One of $|a|\ge|b|$ or $|a|\lt|b|$ must be true, so we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Obsevre that if $ |a|-|b|\ge0 $ then $|b|-|a|\le |a-b|\le |a|-|b|$. ( $\therefore$ in this case $||b|-|a||\le|a-b|$  ).

Also observe that if $ |b|-|a|>0 $ then $|a|-|b|\le |a-b|\le |b|-|a|$. ( $\therefore$ in this case $||b|-|a||\le|a-b|$  ).

Hence $|a|-|b|\le|a-b|$ and $|b|-|a|\le|a-b|$ $ \Rightarrow $ $||b|-|a||\le|a-b|$.

Comment: Is a good way to mathematical express this by saying:
$\pm(|a|-|b|)\le|a-b| \Rightarrow ||a|-|b||\le|a-b|$

I think that's it, right?

Comment: @Douglas $||a|-|b||\le |a-b|\iff \begin{cases}|a|-|b|\le |a-b|\text{ when }|a|\ge |b|\\|b|-|a|\le |a-b|\text{ when }|a|<|b|\end{cases}$, but you know these hold, so q.e.d. I think your way of writing $\pm$ should universally be understood (by $\pm$ you probably meant $\pm x\stackrel{\le}\ge y\implies ((x\stackrel{\le}\ge y)\wedge (-x\stackrel{\le}\ge y))$). You could also say $((x>y)\wedge (-x>y))\implies \max\{x,-x\}=|x|>y$.